# Book about an alien invasion with: a disease, a dead person's mansion, aliens playing in the water, and a missile launch at Vandenberg AFB

Tags: story-identification, books, alien-invasion

I'm looking for a book about an alien invasion. I can recall that there's a disease that kills a lot of people, and this man is in some dead person's mansion, possibly in Los Angeles.

I believe the man worked for the mansion owner in some capacity and took over his house. I think there may have been a woman with him.

Later on, they find some aliens playing in the water and eventually go to Vandenberg Air Force Base to launch a missile at the alien ship. Sorry if I'm mixing the details of two books, but I'm pretty sure I recalled it correctly.

Comment: When did you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  What do you recall of the cover art?

Comment: What man is in the mansion?

Comment: I belive he worked for the man in some capacity, and took over his house. I think there may have been a woman with him

Comment: This reminds me of the video game Deus Ex (from 2000). There is the Ambrosia vaccine for a disease that is killing a large part of the (poorer) population, there is an ongoing alien invasion, and there is the Vandenberg research facility (?) where a mission takes place. Could it have been a novelisation of the game's plot?

Comment: @Joachim In Deus Ex there is no alien invasion; Greys are a product of genetic engineering, a failed attempt at making humans immune to radiation. There is a missile launch thou (that targets Area 51)

Comment: @Negdo Ah, alright, it's been a while :) But there is a Vandenberg Air Force base!